# How can I make news feeds appear from Facebook page owner using the Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook

Does anybody know how to make news feeds appear as from Facebook Page owner?
IE. I have few page admins on FB, and I have Facebook Integration on my website (PHP), and when someone posting announcements on Facebook thru the website all that feeds are appearing as personal feeds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to prompt the admin for the additional scope of "manage_pages", then access /me/accounts to get a list of access_token's and pages they manage, and then post a message like normal using that special access_token.  There is a good walk through of this: http://www.sergiy.ca/post-on-facebook-app-wall-and-fan-page-wall-as-admin/